# How to display the information in single-row columns once, but continue to display information in the multiple-row column in the same result set?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am doing a report on the desktops in my company and the software programs that are currently installed on it.

For example, let's say we have three columns that are guaranteed to return only one row per machine: `Location, Last_logged-on_User, Machine_Name` and one that will return one or more rows: `Software`. I want the first row to display all the single-row columns as well as the first row of the Software column and the rest of rows displaying only the Software rows and fill the single-row columns with blanks.

```
Location Last_logged-on_User Machine_Name Software_name
Venus    James.Jiao          McKain       Internet Explorer
                                          Firefox
                                          Antivirus X
                                          Office Suite
Mars     Veronica.Mars       Obama        Internet Explorer
                                          Google Chrome
                                          Adobe Acrobat
Jupiter  Taylor.Swift        Bachmann     Opera
                                          Speech Helper
                                          Dictionary for Kids
```

I am looking for the query for this, but I am not quite sure how to start with this as I can't think of way to conditionally blank the single-row columns in some rows.

Here is the table structure if you need it

```
Create table Machine
(
  machine_id int not null,
  machine_name varchar(25) not null,
  last_logged-on_user varchar(25) not null,
  location varchar(25) not null
)

Create table SoftwareList
( 
  machine_id int not null,
  software_name varchar(25) not null
)
```

Comment: I have included the table structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Row_Number() Over (Partition by` to establish whether it is the first occurrence in a subquery, and then use a case statement to only return location when row number is 1.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RowNo = 1 OR RowNo IS NULL THEN location ELSE '' END as Location,
    Software_name

FROM (
  SELECT 
        sl.Software_name ,
        m.location,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by location ORDER by location) as rowNo
  FROM Machine m
  LEFT JOIN Softwarelist sl
  ON sl.Machine_id = m.machine_id


  ) d
```

See SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecef5/6)

Hope that helps

Comment: This works like a charm. I suspected row_number() would be involved somehow, but didn't have the mental acuity to get beyond that!